# non-local function call local type

Tags: c++

```
   432     void RoleExternModel::getShareConfig(SourceList& sourceList, std::vector<UInt16>& packs, ShopModel& shopModel)
   433     {
   434         std::copy(Packs, Packs + SHARE_PRIZE, std::insert_iterator<std::vector<UInt16> >(packs, packs.begin()));
   435         struct Fun {
   436             std::vector<std::pair<UInt16, UInt8> > pairs;
   437             void operator () (UInt16 type) {
   438                 pairs.push_back(std::make_pair<UInt16, UInt8>(type, Configuration::PACKS));
   439             }
   440         };
   441         Fun fun();
   442         std::for_each(Packs, Packs + SHARE_PRIZE, fun);
   443         shopModel shopModel(fun.pairs);
   444         shopModel.load(sourceList);
   445     }
```

why the  compiler said :

> error: non-local function
>   ‘Pet::RoleExternModel::getShareConfig(Pet::SourceList&,
>   std::vector >&,
>   Pet::ShopModel&)::Fun Pet::fun()’ uses local type
>   ‘Pet::RoleExternModel::getShareConfig(Pet::SourceList&,
>   std::vector >&,
>   Pet::ShopModel&)::Fun’

how to make it legel?

Comment: We gonna need a complete self-contained test case to have any hope of helping.

Comment: `Fun fun();` or `Fun fun;` ,I doubt!!!

Comment: Fun fun(); -- one issue... if fixing that doesn't help, then we'd need to see more.. for instance, Packs? what type is Packs? I see 'packs'..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
Fun fun();
```

It declares a *function* names `fun` that takes no arguments and returns a `Fun` object.

This is called [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Remove the parentheses and you declare an object named `fun` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are technically correct on the compiler error, but miss a subtle point: `fun` is used incorrectly. It appears to be intended as a local variable that collects results in `fun.pairs`. However, `std::for_each` can copy `fun` instead, and then `fun.pairs` is not updated.

Correct solution: `Fun fun = std::for_each(Packs, Packs + SHARE_PRIZE, Fun());`.